# android: stopping mediaplayer when the activity is destroyed

Tags: android, media-player, ondestroy

I have 2 buttons that play sounds, with the coding as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

    buttonSound1 = MediaPlayer.create(Violin.this,R.raw.violin1);
    buttonSound2 = MediaPlayer.create(Violin.this,R.raw.violin2);

...
}
```

Then on button press:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View view)
     {                                       
         if (b1 %2 == 0)
         {
             button1.setText("STOP!");
             button2.setText("Song 2");
             if(buttonSound1.isPlaying()) buttonSound1.stop();
             if(buttonSound2.isPlaying()) {buttonSound2.stop(); b2++;}                   
             buttonSound1 = MediaPlayer.create(Violin.this,R.raw.violin1);               
             buttonSound1.start();   
         }
         else
         {
             button1.setText("Song 1");
             button2.setText("Song 2");
             if(buttonSound1.isPlaying()) buttonSound1.stop();
             if(buttonSound2.isPlaying()) {buttonSound2.stop(); b2++;}                   
         }
         b1++;   
     }
});
```

### OnDestroy:

```
@Override  
protected void onDestroy() 
{    

    // stop the sounds
    if(buttonSound1.isPlaying()) buttonSound1.stop(); buttonSound1.release();  
    if(buttonSound2.isPlaying()) buttonSound2.stop(); buttonSound2.release();  

    super.onDestroy();  
}
```

### Question:

When the button 1 is playing sound, button 2's sound must be stopped, vice versa.

When I finish the activity (destroyed), the sound is still playing till its end without stopped.

I doubt whether this is because the buttonSound1 is created inside the `onClickListener` and hence cannot be stopped when on destroyed? I have tried to remove such `MediaPlayer.create` lines but then when the button 1 is pressed to stop the sound, when pressed again to play, it simply cannot play any sounds anymore.

How could the above be modified such that:

1. button 1 playing then button 2 must be stopped, vice versa
2. button 1 and 2 sounds will stopped immediately when the activity is finished.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of android and are you sure `onDestroyed()` is getting called?

Comment: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

Comment: Ohh I get it, I am sorry I misunderstood. I thought you were wondering why it didn't stop. I think you should use a service like @rup35h says. Also using one `MediaPlayer` and keeping track of it rather than one for each song, would be much easier to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify this code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
buttonSound1= MediaPlayer.create(x.this,R.raw.sound);
if(buttonSound1.isPlaying())
{
  buttonSound1.stop();
  buttonSound1.release();
}
}
```

Comment: what means by `services`?

Comment: thanks so much for your detailed info, I am actually also think of adding a background music and that then I can use the `Services`. Yet here in this activity I would like to have the sounds be stopped upon the destroy of the activity...if that how could that be modified?

Comment: don't forgot to put super.onDestroy(); inside onDestroy();

Comment: this works better =) I would like to ask, is the activity still not yet destroyed when it is finished (intent and switched to another activity to run). I find that it still plays for a while after gone to another activity. If I put the `stop()` and `release()` in `onBackPressed`, the sounds will immediately stopped instead.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: If u got what you were looking for. Upvote the answer and accept it.

Comment: what is this kind of answer?